# How do I create static folder within a blueprint in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a flask web application, the website has two pages: the main page and the second page, all the files for the second page is stored in a folder called "secondpage" and runs using the main page, which is also the main **app**.py file.

In the secondpage folder, I have two folders: static and templates, as well as a **init**.py file and a **second**.py file, which is the blueprint.

The main page also has a static and templates folder, which is not in a parent folder like secondpage.

Now, the main problem I am facing is using the static folder from secondpage, it just doesn't seem to work, I get a 404 error but I'm not sure why as the static folder has a css and png file in it

Whenever I try to reference the contents in the static folder, it doesn't work.

However, if I reference the static folder of the main page, it seems to work, although it is not in the same folder as secondpage.

I was hoping I could create different blueprint folders, which would be a different page in the website and have their blueprint python and init file, with different styling/image in each static folders.

I tried to do some renaming, such as adding _2 to the static folder name and whatnot, didn't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

In flask you can create a static folder within a blueprint by passing the static_folder to Blueprint class

`new_app = Blueprint("new_app", __name__, template_folder="templates", static_folder="static")`

so if the above app has a url_prefix eg '/new_app', the static folder for the blueprint is '/new_app/static'

This static folder which contains the static files should be placed inside the same folder which contains the blueprint.